# Sparse matrix design in modern C++

Tags: c++14, sparse-matrix, c++17, library-design

I want to implement a sparse matrix class using modern c++ ie 14 or 17. I know there must be some trade offs between storage and runtime efficiency. Right now I'd prefer to optimize more in terms of storage efficiency. If possible, I'd prefer more work to be done at compile time rather than runtime. For example, vector does have a lot of runtime checks so it may not be optimal. Can someone suggest a container for this? I plan to support the following operations:

```
Matrix Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction, Inversion and Transpose
Matrix iterators ie column row
Efficient constructors 
etc
```

Thanks!

Comment: What "runtime checks" does a `vector` do that make it not be optimal? I think it mostly follows the principle of "you don't pay for what you don't use".

Comment: You don't appear to be competent enough to solve this problem yet.  Start with a simple problem, like a dense contiguous matrix, get an idea of performance characteristics of underlying containers, read some papers on sparse matrix operations, and come back in a year or so?

Comment: Is the list above complete? I.e. What about solvers / Eigenvalue / SVD etc? The checks are not an issue. They are way cheaper that the operations. Memory alignment / iterators are the much much bigger task. What about the precision i.e. complex or real, float or doubles? What about use of external libraries? Fourier / Wavelet? All of this matters, when you want to design something like that. I am the author or github.com/kvahed/codeare. I envy you for the project, btw.

Comment: Do you want COO? CSR? RSC? And then there are plenty other choices of sparse matrices, each of them adapted for different goals.